# Loop through objects and form a json format for submission to an endpoint, avoiding the forEach is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the JSON structure I want to send to an end point.

```
{
   "reporter_tags":[
      {
         "reporter":"6af252d8-aa7c-4bce-ae31-7z4593f7c0f0",
         "tag":"5c80823c-a800-42b5-8ba6-ac00f49f35db"
      },
      {
         "reporter":"6af252d8-aa7c-4bce-ae31-7z4593f7c0f0",
         "tag":"4c6fae97-476d-4c0c-a858-0272dc91cc03"
      },
      {
         "reporter":"1510ba30-dcaf-4d47-a3fc-6p211fbcb324",
         "tag":"5c80823c-a800-42b5-8ba6-ac00f49f35db"
      },
      {
         "reporter":"1510ba30-dcaf-4d47-a3fc-6p211fbcb324",
         "tag":"4c6fae97-476d-4c0c-a858-0272dc91cc03"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the code I have written to achieve this structure, but it only works for arrays. My goal to make sure the code works for objects.

```
// const idArray = this.selectedReporters; // is supposed to be reporter Ids
const idArray = ['6af252d8-aa7c-4bce-ae31-7d4593f7c0f0', '1510ba30-dcaf-4d47-a3fc-6f211fbcb324'] // is supposed to be reporter Ids
// const tagArray = this.formGroup.value; // is supposed to hold selected tags
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
const tagArray = ['5c80823c-a800-42b5-8ba6-ac00f49f35db', '4c6fae97-476d-4c0c-a858-0272dc91cc03'] // is supposed to hold selected tags
const tagArr = [];

idArray.forEach((el) => {
    tagArray.forEach((ll) => {
        tagArr.push({
            reporter: el,
            tag: ll
        })
    })
    /*for (let [key, name] of Object.entries(tagArray)) {
      tagArr.push({reporter: el, tag: name })
    }*/
})
const reporterTags = {
    reporter_tags: tagArr
}
console.log(reporterTags);
```

when I use the objects that are commented out and the same code, I get tagArray.forEach not a function.

If you look at the code I commented out within my function, I used that to loop through the object, but it won't return the data in the format I need.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does `this.formGroup.value` look like? Maybe you have a console.log of that which you can show? You probably don't want nested loops for that I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was coming up because of the way I assigned the value of tagArray.
First of all, remove the arrays ie.

```
const idArray = ['6af252d8-aa7c-4bce-ae31-7d4593f7c0f0', '1510ba30-dcaf-4d47-a3fc-6f211fbcb324'] 
const tagArray = ['5c80823c-a800-42b5-8ba6-ac00f49f35db', '4c6fae97-476d-4c0c-a858-0272dc91cc03']
```

then uncomment:

```
// const idArray = this.selectedReporters;
// const tagArray = this.formGroup.value;
```

the correct way is;

```
const tagArray = this.formGroup.controls.tags.value;
```

and not;

```
const tagArray = this.formGroup.value;
```

My form Group was in this way;

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      tags: [''],
    });
```

Thats why this.formGroup.controls.tags.value;  was the correct way of assigning.